# Failed to download respository information - Software Updater

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

I run Ubuntu 14.04LTS, 64bit. I tried to run Software Updater, but I had that "Failed to download respository information. Check your Internet connection" message ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVrX.png)).

[image]

I ran `apt-get update`, and it gave me this :

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to change the mirror server to several others, including "Main server", but the result is the same. The error seems to come from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Here is `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted non-free
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse main non-free restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse main non-free restricted universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports multiverse main non-free restricted universe
```

Here is `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` :

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

I also unchecked all "Other Software" boxes in "Software & Updates" program, just to see if the problem comes from an unofficial packet, but it seems not.
Any idea to solve it ?

Comment: My problem was a bit different since the error message was different. However, you are right, the background of the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in terminal this line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/\ non-free//' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

this will change the following lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and leave out the `non-free` so they look like this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

.
.
.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports multiverse main restricted universe
```

this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse main non-free restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse main non-free restricted universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports multiverse main non-free restricted universe
```

`non-free` is not an Ubuntu component. That's Debian. The Ubuntu equivalents are `restricted` and `multiverse`. Ubuntu just has `main`, `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse`.